# Converting video into frames using openCV

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, image-recognition

### I am converting video into video-frames using the given code

## converting video into frames

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Playing video from file:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/administrator/Desktop/Projects/gait-     recognition/video/p008-n05.avi')
frames = []
try:
        if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')
except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data')
currentFrame = 0
while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
   # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
   name = './data/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'
print ('Creating...' + name)
cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
frames.append(frame)
# To stop duplicate images
currentFrame += 1
if ret == False:
   break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
```

### imgs = np.array(frames)

which is giving me output as images in the form of a single multi-dimensional array. This is required here as

---

## Create features from input frames in shape (TIME, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS)

```
spatial_features = net_pose.feed_forward_features(imgs)
```

When I feed the images as `video_frames` in this, I get this error as follows:

[image: Error]

Please tell me where and what modifications are required to get the desired tensor.

Comment: What is net_pose?

Comment: net_pose is an object of the same class. The question is how can i get the 'imgs' tensor in  shape (TIME, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS) using openCV?